# Double Pipe ||= operator work in console but don't work in server

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

```
class Test
  def settings
   @setting ||= load_user_env
  end

  def load_user_env
   {one: 'Test'}
  end
end


t = Test.new
t.settings
t.settings
```

In the rails console `load_user_env` method is called once, but in development environment on WEBrick it gets called every time?

How can it be?

Comment: I use WEBrick on development, sorry for misprint.

Comment: What do you mean that it is called every time?  Do you mean that it is called every request?  If so, that is intended behavior... variables have a lifetime per request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** The instance variable should only persist in the context of each request, so it should be reinitialized each time you make a request. In your console, when you do `t = Test.new`, you create a single instance of the class, so that's why `load_user_env` only gets called once. You could use a class variable `@@setting`, which should be persistent across requests and instances of `Test`, but I'm not sure how reloading the classes in dev mode will affect that.

Rails reloads the classes in development mode on every request. In the console, it doesn't unless you call `reload!`.

If you set `config.cache_classes = true` for your development environment, it shouldn't reload them anymore and it should also make it faster. The downside is then you have to restart the server every time you make a change.

Comment: How would this affect the lifetime of a variable?  `config.cache_classes` caches the classes themselves, preventing them from being pull from disk on every request, but the instances are going to live within the scope of a request, right?

Comment: Ah, yes. The instance variable should only persist within the scope of the request.